# Magento 2.2.2 - Web setup wizard stuck on Rollback

Tags: magento2.2.2, web-setup-wizard

My website is stuck on rollback, how do I disable this?

[image]

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the update_in_progress flag inside your /var directory.
Worked for me.

Comment: For me, removing the hidden file `.update_error.flag` worked.